# Geometric distribution, rolling a dice

Tags: probability

We roll a fair dice until we get a number $3$. We win as many dollars as is a number of times we didn't get a $3$. If we get $3$ in a first throw, we loose $y$ dollars. What is the maximum value for $y$ so that this game is profitable for us?

I don't really know where to start. Of course I'd like to compute some kind of expectancy, but how to include this information about a possible outcome of a first roll?

Comment: is the dollar amount won equal to the number of times we did not get a $3$ or is it the sum of face values in those throws?

Comment: @MathLover number of times we did not get a 3.

Comment: Then consider this - expected number of throws to get $3$ is $6$ which means expected dollar amount you can make is $5$. This should be more than $\frac{y}{6}$.

Comment: If that does not convince you, set up the geometric series. It should lead to the same answer.

Comment: @MathLover so you agree with the answer $18$?

Comment: No that is not what I said. Please check my earlier comment. Does that lead to $18$?

Comment: @MathLover I don't really know how to combine these two facts.

Comment: I simply said $5 \gt \frac{y}{6}$. $5$ is the dollar amount you are expected to win and $\frac{y}{6}$ is the dollar amount you are expected to lose.

Comment: @MathLover oh, sure, then $y \leq 30$.

Comment: yes you can set up geometric series to confirm that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p = \frac{5}{6}$ and let $q = (1-p)$.

First, preliminary results:

$S = \sum_{n=0}^\infty p^n = \frac{1}{1-p} = 6.$

$T = \sum_{n=1}^\infty np^{n-1} = 
1 + 2p + 3p^2 + \cdots$ 
$= S \times (1 + p + p^2 + \cdots) = S^2 = 36.$

---

There are two possibilities:
1st roll is $3$, which results in $-y$.  This case has an expectation of $-qy$.

First roll is not $3$, which means that you win money.  
This scenario has a probability of occuring of $p$.

Once it is given that the first roll is not $3$, the chance of you winning exactly $n$ is given by $qp^{(n-1)}.$  Therefore, assuming that your first roll is not $3$, your expected profit is

$q \times (1 + 2p + 3p^2 + \cdots) = qT.$

Therefore, your positive expectation is represented by
$p \times qT = 5.$

Therefore, your overall expectation is

$$5 - qy$$.

Therefore, for the game to be break-even, $y = 30.$

Answer (score 0):

The expections numbers of throws till getting $3$ is obviously $6$, since its a bernoulli distribution with $p(x=3)=\frac{1}{6}$ and $p(x\neq3)=\frac{5}{6}$.

In every throw we did'nt throw $3$ the expection is:

$E(X)=0.2\cdot(1+2+4+5+6)=3.6$

So we expect for $5 \cdot 3.6=18$ so the maximnum $y$ would be $18$

I used 5 and not 6, since its the time of throwing without getting 3.